# Next Js build give error 500 internal server error in some routes

Tags: node.js, next.js

I'm trying to make the page in question `getServerSideProps` because the content is list of products through API so `getStaticProps` isnt going to help with this page.
but unfortunately all the pages work perfectly on `localhost` but when i deploy on vercel the page in question is giving me 500 internal server error.

any help?

build log:

[image: build log (the page is "produits")]

error:

[image: error]

folder structure:

[image: folder structure]

```
export async function getStaticProps(context) {
  const { host } = context.params;

  const headersTn = {
    domain: "tn",
  };

  const headersDz = {
    domain: "dz",
  };

  const headersCi = {
    domain: "ci",
  };

  const resTn = await fetch(`${process.env.urlApi}v1/getProductsByCountry/`, {
    headers: headersTn,
  }).then((res) => res.json());
  const resDz = await fetch(`${process.env.urlApi}v1/getProductsByCountry/`, {
    headers: headersDz,
  }).then((res) => res.json());
  const resCi = await fetch(`${process.env.urlApi}v1/getProductsByCountry/`, {
    headers: headersCi,
  }).then((res) => res.json());

  const langParam = await fetch(`${process.env.urlApi}v1/getLanguage/`).then(
    (res) => res.json()
  );

  return {
    props: {
      host,
      tn: resTn,
      dz: resDz,
      ci: resCi,
      dataLang: langParam,
    },
  };
}

export async function getStaticPaths(context) {
  const paths = context.locales.map((locale) => {
    return { params: { host: `${process.env.staticHost}` }, locale };
  });

  return {
    paths,
    fallback: "blocking",
  };
}
```

Comment: Did you push your `.env` to the deployment build?

Comment: What error do the Vercel logs show when you access the page?

Comment: the problem was indeed in the environement variables as i didnt change all the url's in the .env files . I solved it by simply changing my variables